# Prevent add text in MahApp datepicker?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to prevent to add text in `MahApp` datepicker, what I tried so far is this:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker">
        <DatePicker.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.Resources>
    </DatePicker>
```

that was essentially a code taken from a question already asked on so, but in this case the code above not working, I can insert all the character type in my `DatePicker`.

I tried also `Focusable = false` but this will cause problem with my popup so I discarded this solution. Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of `MahApps` are you using?  When using the latest `MahApps.Metro` from NuGet, the solution you quoted works perfectly.

Comment: @MikeStrobel are you using the pre release of the last release? I'm using the last release 1.5

Comment: I'm using the stable `1.5.0` release.

Comment: me too, and when I type the text inside I can see it

Comment: And you're using the 'standard' resources?  I'm importing `Controls.xaml`, `Fonts.xaml`, `Colors.xaml`, `Accents/Blue.xaml`, and `Accents/BaseLight.xaml` (all under `Styles` in the `MahApps.Metro` assembly).  If our setups match, then something else is probably going on.  Are you pulling in any style resources from elsewhere?

Comment: I'm using also MDIX (material design in xaml) but the resource of MahApp are included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using also MDIX (material design in xaml) but the resource of MahApp are included

According to the [Material Design styles](http://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.DatePicker.xaml), they are using a different style key for the date picker's text box (see lines 13 and 177 behind the link).  Just add `x:Key="MaterialDesignDatePickerTextBox"` to your `Style` declaration, and you should be good to go:

```xml
<DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker">
  <DatePicker.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MaterialDesignDatePickerTextBox"
           TargetType="DatePickerTextBox"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDatePickerTextBox}">
      <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
  </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

As a rule, if you are pulling in style resources from somewhere, and something isn't working as you expect, the first thing you should do is consult the Xaml for those styles.  Chances are good that they're deviating from the normal conventions in some way.

Comment: I get `MaterialDesignDatePickerTextBox` is not supported in a wpf project

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get that, but I updated my answer to show what your declaration should look like.

Comment: your solution working but lost the style of the datepicker textbox

Comment: this working for you? 'cause I get a textbox with no style

Comment: Well, it looks pretty simple (almost style-less), but that's exactly what the date picker looks like when I comment out the custom style and use the material design defaults.